# Cannot control Remote Pc when clicked on textbox

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services

I have developed a Remote Desktop Server and Client in c# using

```
AxInterop.RDPCOMAPILib.dll and RDPCOMPLIB.DLL.
```

every thing works fine i can view and remotely control the pc . But the problem arises on viewing side a side on which i am seeing and controlling the remote pc , problem is that when i click on textbox on my program then i can't access the session means i cant control Remote pc but i can only view its activity that what is happening on remote side.

So whats the problem how can be it solved.

Comment: Can you interact with anything on the remote PC? If not, are you sure the mouse pointer has been shared?

Comment: No , i can only view the remote pc and all activity on it but cannot access means cannot click on its desktop , in simple words it becomes only remote viewer.

Comment: What do you have `ControlLevel` set to for the session?

Comment: Interactive control level

Comment: Can you share some of your code please?

Comment: Yes download Whole project from this link...

https://www.mediafire.com/?whlfzeudq9di1y3

Comment: Please help me i will be so much thankfull to u..

Comment: I can't download the files sorry! Can you copy and paste some code into your question instead?